# How to access Ubuntu desktop from a Windows system?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, remote-desktop

When using Terminal Server Client, it is possible to access the Windows desktop (remote desktop), from an Ubuntu PC.

Is the reverse possible?

What is the Windows XP application used to connect to an Ubuntu desktop?

Is the default **mstsc** application sufficient? If yes, what are the required settings on Ubuntu and Windows?

I want to *view the desktop*, *not just an SSH terminal access*.

Comment: Another option is X2go. Tutorial available [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/825313/594621)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) to do just that in a Windows system.

Comment: Teamviewer is pure awesomeness!!! +1 for Teamviewer!

Answer (score 2):

I used Remote Desktop to connect to my Ubuntu box. xrdp on the Ubuntu box is an adequate rdp server.

Tips [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/connect-to-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-via-windows-remote-desktop/) on getting it working if you're having problems with nothing displaying (except the background).

Answer (score 1):

you can try [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) . And it's a [simple guide](http://www.skullbox.net/vncserver.php) to use tightVNC. Hope this helps

Comment: +1, it did worked for me...But it's not as clean as rdp

Answer (score 0):

If you have XP Professional, one can also use [Remmina remote Desktop Client](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) on the Ubuntu side and just straight RDP to get to the XP machine. Simple VNC viewer will work in reverse. I always liked UltraVNC on the XP side.