# Access Ubuntu from xp by remote desktop

Tags: software-recommendation, 14.04, windows-xp, remote-desktop, vnc

I want to access 14.04 via remote desktop from xp. I installed vnc4server on my 14.04 system following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server). Now what to do afterwards? Do I need to install some thing on xp? vnc client for xp? Maybe I can follow [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48013/how-to-access-ubuntu-desktop-from-a-windows-system). All I need is to access the 14.04 desktop from xp. So if there is a solution, please just tell me:

1. what I need to install on 14.04, and
2. what I need to install on xp.

Comment: You need to configure either the client or the server so that both use the same port.

Comment: @I suggest your link myself AS 'this' on my question . please take a look on that page they just say so general.I edited the question . you say on client and server so what program exactly

Comment: I did that in the past, I used XP as host machine. Check out my old topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377445/how-can-i-connect-ubuntu-through-windows-via-localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you also need to install VNC client on your XP machine. What are the numbers of your ports, which seemed to be differ? Ports should be the same. Just in case, If (some of) ports are busy and/or home router with number machines are involved you may need to use port forwarding.
EDIT:
For XP try [TightVnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php). I tried it, worked well for me. For Ubuntu it is X11VNC Server from basic repositary. `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`

Comment: Copying answers into a duplicate question is pushing the limits of what is the acceptable conduct in this web site.

Comment: @Ruslan I edited please tell what the exact name for xp and what the exact name for ubuntu

Comment: Alex, for XP try [TightVnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php). I tried it, worked well for me.

Comment: @Ruslan thank you very much, what about for server which in here is 14.04 do you try anything for that too?

Comment: yes, for Ubuntu it is X11VNC Server from basic repositary. `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`

Comment: @Ruslan I tried and worked,thanks really appreciate your help.