# How to access remote desktop from a Windows PC to Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, windows, remote-desktop

How to access a ubuntu system remotely from a windows pc without teamviewer? Is there any other option.

Comment: Do you know about this one: http://www.putty.org/ ?

Comment: Unless you have direct access or SSH so you can install VNC or Remote Desktop, I don't believe there's a way. If you need to access it from another physical location (across the internet), then you'll have to set up port forwarding, and a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several options to access Ubuntu GUI from a Windows machine...

- Teamviewer is pretty good, secure and user-friendly but it takes **HUGE** amounts of RAM on the Windows Machine (never bothered to look on the linux part but I guess it's not much better).
- VNC (real, tight, tiger...) is incredibly lightweight, fast and easy to use but, because of it's pretty weak security, it should only be used within well-secured LANs
- X2go is, *IMHO*, a pretty good compromise and my personnal favorite (thought it does **NOT** work correctly with Unity, but LXDE, MATE or XFCE will work perfectly, please make sure you install one before you continue).
  Note that the Windows client is 32bit and won't work on 64bit-only architecture (Itanium...) but that's kinda specific.

Here is a small Howto deal with the somewhat tricky installation of X2go for Ubuntu Trusty (14.04 LTS), based on my own experience (*ymmv*)

Before even starting, check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with your favorite text editor (***sudo*** it, of course).
Make sure that, among the `deb http://whatever.ubuntu.something/ubuntu trusty` lines, at least ONE must end with `main universe`.
If you're not sure, or if no line seems to match and you freak at the idea of messing up , just add the following line:
`deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe`
Save and `sudo apt-get update`

Now, let's start
First, make sure you can add the repository:
`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`
(this should tell you last version is already installed but better be sure than sorry)
Now add the repository
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update`
Now, let's install X2go:
`sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession`
*If you have installed LXDE, you may add the `x2golxdebindings` package (there is also a `x2gomatebindings` for MATE, but not yet for XFCE, which is not a very big deal anyways).*

The X2go Windows client installer can be downloaded here (there's also clients for Mac OS X if you need it):
http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start

Configuring the client is easy: server address, username and session type (LXDE, XFCE or MATE ar recommended: others are note working proprely, as said before).
You will probably have to accept a SSH key on your first connection.

**NOTE**: upon connection your client **may** get an error stating `stdin is not a valid TTY`.
In that case, get on the server and ***sudo*** edit your root's `.profile` and locate a single line stating `mesg n`.
Delete that line and replace it with the following:
`if 'tty -s'; then
  mesg n
  TTY="tty"
else
  TTY='not a tty'
fi`
Save, exit and
`sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart`
to apply changes.
Should work

Answer (score 0):

Install x11vnc. Here is an [installation guide](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Easy-VNC-control-on-Linux-and-Xorg-with-x11vnc) for it:

> It is possible to share your X desktop, in a Windows way with x11vnc: install it with `sudo apt-get install x11vnc and run it with
>
> ```
> x11vnc -display :0
> ```
>
> x11vnc will print something like
>
> ```
> The VNC desktop is:      escher:0
> PORT=5900
> ```
>
> Now you can simply connect to your desktop with vncviewer on port 5900.
>
> It is even possible to connect the viewer automatically (very useful for bypassing firewalls) with:
>
> ```
> x11vnc -display :0 -connect host:port
> ```
>
> where host has a listening viewer on port, for example ultraVNC supports this feature.
>
> Notice that it is important to deactivate any 3D software on your desktop as x11vnc obviously cannot transport OpenGL graphics.
>
> It even has a graphical interface.
>
> ```
> x11vnc -gui
> ```
>
> Also notice that it would be very easy to make an automatic remote control script for assisting people on Linux. On your side, open a port in your firewall and run vncviewer in listen mode. On the client side, send him a shell script that checks if x11vnc is installed and runs `x11vnc -display :0 -connect you:your-port`.